# Payload for sqs message when using arraylist and objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

while trying to send message to sqs , during parsing receiving error :

```
{"message":"Exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: (String)\
```

**Class structure:**

```
data class TriggerPayoutPayload(
    val customerId: String,
    val bookingType: BookingEntityType,
    val itemsId: List<ListItems>?,
)

enum class BookingEntityType {
    PREBOOKED,
    RETURN,
}

enum class ItemType {
    HEALTH,
    BEVERAGE,
}

data class ListItems(
    val itemType: ItemType,
    val description: List<String>,
)
```

**Used below payload :**

```
{
"type": "test.payout",
"id":"sqsMsgId-01-03-01",
"body": {
"customer_id": "cus123",
"booking_type": "PREBOOKED",
"items_id":["{"item_type":"HEALTH","description":"Healthy"}"]
}
}
```

Code fails to parse event.payload with TriggerPayoutPayload. Only log statement printed but cannot proceed to **payoutProcessor.process()**

**Sqs event processing:**

```
private fun eventsProcessor(sqsEvent: SqsEvent<*>) {
log.info("Handling event ${sqsEvent.id} type: ${sqsEvent.type}")
        when (sqsEvent.type) {
            PREBOOKED ->
                payoutProcessor.process(
                    sqsEvent.payload as TriggerPayoutPayload,
                )
}


data class SqsEvent<T>(
    val id: String,
    val time: Instant? = null,
    val type: String,
@JsonSubTypes(
        Type(value = TriggerPayoutPayload::class, name = "PREBOOKED"))

val payload: T? = null,
    val metadata: EventMetadata? = null,
    var messageId: String? = null,
    var receiptHandler: String? = null)
```

**StackTrace**

```
{"message":"Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.testproject.checkout.britania.migration.domain.TriggerPayoutPayload, stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.testproject.checkout.britania.migration.domain.TriggerPayoutPayload\n\tat com.testproject.checkout.britania.migration.ApplicationHandler.eventsProcessor(ApplicationHandler.kt:114)\n\tat com.testproject.checkout.britania.migration.ApplicationHandler.handleRequest(ApplicationHandler.kt:72)\n\tat com.testproject.checkout.britania.migration.ApplicationHandler.handleRequest(ApplicationHandler.kt:35)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:202)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:905)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:245)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:197)\n\tat
```

Comment: Looks like the payload is not valid. There is unwanted double quote in the array.  Try this formatted payload.

{
   "type":"test.payout",
   "id":"sqsMsgId-01-03-01",
   "body":{
      "customer_id":"cus123",
      "booking_type":"PREBOOKED",
      "items_id":[
         {
            "item_type":"HEALTH",
            "description":"Healthy"
         }
      ]
   }
}

Comment: @MANISH Thanks for looking into it. But looks like now i'm getting {"message":"Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type.                                                                                                                           Looks like some issue in assigning values to "List<ListItems>?"

Comment: Can you share the exception stacktrace please ?

Comment: Most relevant log in only null pointer exception. I'm guessing something wrong with how we are passing values for List of Objects

Comment: Added stacktrace in above problem description

Comment: @RahulBhandari Add info to the question how you updated the payload based on the comment. Also, share the code that's receiving the payload and does the parsing. Without it, no one can tell you what's wrong

Comment: @Caldazar Done adding code for receiving the payload